# How ToR meek client works?

Tags: pluggable-transports, meek

Before posting, I've already read these suggested links: [meek-client](https://www.antitree.com/2014/09/07/meek-protocol/) ..  [pluggable transports](https://tor.stackexchange.com/q/12553/14395) so my question is not duplicate. Rather it is an extension to that question. Meek client hides your ToR traffic from your ISP but it's working is quite complicated. in short it works like this [How meek works](https://www.bamsoftware.com/papers/fronting/meek-architecture.svg)
In this picture you can see that Intermediate fronted server is decrypting the packet and forwarding the forbidden.example-> which is meek server itself. I understand ISP can't do this as it is encrypted request but the fronted server can easily block this "not allowed" domain because it knows that the request is made for meek server. **Why the Content Delivery Network Fronted server is not blocking client request for connecting to meek server??** Either fronted server is not intentionally blocking it or it doesn't know that the forbidden.example request is actually a meek server. How it actually works?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've got it right: **All** the pluggable transports can be potentially messed up if set up by an untrusted party, so be careful who you're trusting to. The idea of Meek client is to be a regular HTTPS client, the basic and unspecific, so the probability of DPI detection is degraded greatly. The graph you've referred shows precisely how it works: the *client part* is just a client for HTTPS queries. That's it

Comment: Thnx for adding new information Alexey but that's not the answer I was looking for and did I mention any graph? It was an image of stepwise chain of working of meek. I'm editing my question a little to make it more clear what I'm really asking.

Comment: @user334283 CDN's are *too heavy loaded* to do so. Even some simple rules are impossible to implement on their side: I faced it even in 2016. The answer about CDN's is that, for example, a website with 300k hits per hour is using it, for example, and even rewriting URL's will fry the CDN CPU's to hell... It's technically impossible to implement smart filtering on CDN platform - for whatever purpose - without destroying the CDN concept itself.

Comment: That's why CDN google cloud platform suspended the meek server for violating Terms of Service. https://lists.torproject.org/pipermail/tor-talk/2016-June/041699.html ..But meek server is still running on other CDNs so I think it is upto the CDNs whether or not they want to filter tor request and in this case rather than filtering it, terminating it is a better option for CDNs.

Comment: @user334283 as to my knowledge, Google Cloud is *the most strict* in terms of ToS hardness. So it was not a surprise, that it was terminated. There are lots of CDN networks that do allow much wider usage